# In R, how can I replace the values in one column with the values of another column whenever the replacing column is not empty?

Tags: r, replace, automation, conditional-statements

I'm working on automating a report in R. One thing we do is look at clients who enter a shop and estimate their age record that as *Estimate Age*. We are instructed to use the *Estimated Age* as *Age* in the report so that all parties have an age. If we are able to record someone's *Actual Age* that age then becomes the *Age*. Most records do not have a value for *Actual Age*. For the records that do have an *Actual Age* value I need to replace the *Estimated Age* value with the *Actual Age* value whenever it exists. The records without *Actual Age* should remain unchanged.

I'm a newbie and have been stuck on this step for months. Asking the stackoverflow gods for a blessing. See image if it helps.

[Replacing Estimate Age with Actual Age](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vyi28.png)

I've already tried:
Tried several variations of 2 different methods for replacing Estimated Age with Actual Age, again to no avail:

1) `Age <- ifelse(is.null(MyReport$ActualAge), MyReport$ActualAge, MyReport$EstimatedAge)`

View(MyReport)
2)  Also something like this but I tweaked it so much so not exactly like this I messed it up

```
select <- is.null(MainReportload$ActualAge) < 0.01
df[select,MyReport$EstimatedAge] <- df[select, MyReport$ActualAge]
```

3)

```
if(is.null(MyReport$ActualAge)) {
  MyReport$Age <- MyReport$EstimatedAge
} else {
  MyReport$Age <- MyReport$ActualAge
  }
MyReport$Age
View(MyReport)
```

8.6.19 Alternative based on brain and minimal SQL knowledge, just do a coalesce, coalesce is available in the dplyr library. Result: same issue as the above attempt will continue with research.

Comment: In R, a `data.frame` will not have a `NULL` column; if you assign `NULL` to a column, that column is removed. (There are ways to get the `NULL` value embedded within a column, as a *list-column*, but that takes effort ... and breaks many things.) My guess is that you actually have either `NA` values or empty strings (your picture is almost worthless for details, so I'm guessing). Also, I think you have the yes/no arguments to `ifelse` backwards. Try `ifelse(is.na(MyReport$ActualAge), MyReport$EstimatedAge, MyReport$ActualAge)`.

Comment: Can you add a small reproducible example along with expected output ? You can read about how to give a reproducible example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the problem was the age values were stored as a range always leading with zero. So a 24 year old would have age as 0-24. I couldn’t use the dplyr::coalesce solution until I fixed that price. Also, it didn’t work with the mutate piece so I took that off.

Below is what finally worked for me!

```
    #USING ACTUAL AGE WHENEVER IT IS PRESENT AND ESTIMATED AGE WHEN THERE ISN'T AN ACTUAL AGE
#Remove hyphens from age fields and store the column as integers

main_df$Actual.Age <- as.integer( gsub("-", "", main_df$Actual.Age))
main_df$EstimatedAge <- as.integer( gsub("-", "", main_df$EstimatedAge))


#Use Coalesce to create a new column that contains the NEW Age values. 
main_df$new_EstimatedAge <- dplyr::coalesce(main_df$Actual.Age, 
main_df$EstimatedAge)
#view(head(main_df$new_EstimatedAge, 30))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you say that `dplyr::coalesce` doesn't work, here's a simplified generic example of it. If you post a reproducible version of your data we can help more. The key to coalesce is that it returns the **first** non missing value. So `coalesce(estimated_age, age) != coalesce(age, estimated_age)`

```
# example data
df <- readr::read_csv("
age, estimated_age
12, 14
NA, 13
NA, NA
15, NA
")

# coalesce
df2 <- dplyr::mutate(df, new_age = dplyr::coalesce(age, estimated_age))
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the responses! Part of the problem was the age values were stored as a range always leading with zero. So a 24 year old would have age as 0-24. I couldn’t use your dplyr::coalesce solution until I fixed that price. Also it didn’t work with the mutate piece so I took that off. Stack isn't letting me paste what worked here says it's too long, so I'm gonna do it in a separate comment.